# Teams Calls API, How to unmute a participant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I note it is possible to mute a participant using

[participant mute documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0)

and

```
ICall.Participants[participantID].MuteAsync()
```

There does not seem to be a corresponding unmute API for a participant.

I note that there is Call level unmute which does not specify a participant, this does not affect already muted parties when I tried it

Question  : If I mute a call leg using the above MuteAsync, how do I then unmute it from the API ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no API to unmute the participant, Could you please raise a [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)